# Formtastic alternative that works well with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems, mongoid

Do you know any "semantic" rails gems for form generation which integrates well with the mongoid gem ? By integration I mean, correct automatic association based on the rules in the models (referenced_in, references_many).

I tried simple_form but it seems to fail ...

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formtastic works OK with some tinkering, although not everything will be automatic. I've got a small tutorial app showing some of the things you have to do to get Formtastic to work with Mongoid:

http://github.com/bowsersenior/formtastic_with_mongoid_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

[simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) works fine to me with Mongoid

Comment: are you using it with referenced_in and references_many ? (not embeds_on or embeds_many)

Comment: well for simple forms it works, complex ones we build by hand

Comment: according to this threat https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/635 mongoid si not supported

Comment: It used to work OK with mongoid ~6 but not with mongoid ~7 :(